# Wrapping around old C Structures with smart pointers in C++11 and auto-freeing them

Tags: c++, c, c++11, wordnet

I'm using [Word-Net](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/), an old C library developed by Princeton University back in the nineties.
The library is written in C, and only reveals the headers but not its actual implementation.

The only structure I use is:

```
SynsetPtr
```

And the two functions I call are:

```
findtheinfo_ds

traceptrs_ds
```

Both those functions return a SynsetPtr.

Howevever, when the SynsetPtr represents a sense list, I have to free it using

```
free_syns
```

Whereas, when the SynsetPtr is used to traverse a linked list (a hierarchical tree), I have to free it using

```
free_synset
```

The [Documentation](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/man2.0/wnsearch.3WN.html) is not really clear when to call which, and why.

This is quickly becoming a nightmare for me. I have spent three days working my way slowly through leaks, double frees, memory allocations and such.

So I was wondering, is there a way for me, to wrap around those functions, or the actual Structure, and make C++ manage the memory? Ideally I would want them free'd when there are no more references to them, as is the case with std::shared_ptr.

Is this possible, knowing that Synset_Ptr has no destructor, but a dealloc function has to be called?

Alternatively, could I wrap around the two functions that create (allocate) those structures, somehow book-keep the objects, and destroy them when no references to them remain?

I would really appreciate any help whatsoever!

EDIT:

This is the exact declaration of SynsetPtr in wn.h

```
/* Structure for data file synset */
typedef struct ss {
    long hereiam;       /* current file position */
    int sstype;         /* type of ADJ synset */
    int fnum;           /* file number that synset comes from */
    char *pos;          /* part of speech */
    int wcount;         /* number of words in synset */
    char **words;       /* words in synset */
    int *lexid;         /* unique id in lexicographer file */
    int *wnsns;         /* sense number in wordnet */
    int whichword;      /* which word in synset we're looking for */
    int ptrcount;       /* number of pointers */
    int *ptrtyp;        /* pointer types */
    long *ptroff;       /* pointer offsets */
    int *ppos;          /* pointer part of speech */
    int *pto;           /* pointer 'to' fields */
    int *pfrm;          /* pointer 'from' fields */
    int fcount;         /* number of verb frames */
    int *frmid;         /* frame numbers */
    int *frmto;         /* frame 'to' fields */
    char *defn;         /* synset gloss (definition) */
    unsigned int key;       /* unique synset key */

    /* these fields are used if a data structure is returned
       instead of a text buffer */

    struct ss *nextss;      /* ptr to next synset containing searchword */
    struct ss *nextform;    /* ptr to list of synsets for alternate
                   spelling of wordform */
    int searchtype;     /* type of search performed */
    struct ss *ptrlist;     /* ptr to synset list result of search */
    char *headword;     /* if pos is "s", this is cluster head word */
    short headsense;        /* sense number of headword */
} Synset;

typedef Synset *SynsetPtr;


/* Primary search algorithm for use with programs (returns data structure) */
extern SynsetPtr findtheinfo_ds(char *, int, int, int); 

/* Recursive search algorithm to trace a pointer tree and return results
   in linked list of data structures. */
SynsetPtr traceptrs_ds(SynsetPtr, int, int, int);

/* Free a synset linked list allocated by findtheinfo_ds() */
extern void free_syns(SynsetPtr);   

/* Free a synset */
extern void free_synset(SynsetPtr);
```

And that is essentially all I know.

EDIT 2:

Even though I've used the two answers below, unfortunatelly, the functions are still leaking bytes.

That only seems to happen with:

```
traceptrs_ds ( ptr, SIMPTR, ADJ, 0 )
```

The documentation has very little information about adjective synonyms (-synsa) or other types (-synsn, -synsv).

However, I managed to iterate **most** of them, simply by following the ptr->ptrlist && ptr->nextss;

traceptr_ds iterates **ALL** of them, but I cannot find a way to avoid the leak, even when using a minified test prog.

Thanks to the whoever helped, very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know when you create the objects which type it is (tree or list), and can the type change?

Comment: There's probably no reason why you couldn't wrap the create function in a c++ constructor and call the appropriate free method in a destructor.  Making the wrapping class immutable is going to help a lot.  Then use one of the standard reference counting methods to access your encapsulating class.

Comment: I can infer which is created. The first function creates a linked list of synsets, the second function traverses one of them, by returning a synset pointer in the list. The entire design is really confusing and I've tried to contact the authors to no avail.

Comment: @PeteBaughman Would you be so kind to provide a dummy example? bear in mind that when doing a Breadth-First-Search, I cannot deallocate previous Structures in the list, until I don't need them any more.

Comment: @Alex Do you have the source for `traceptrs_ds` available? It looks like that function calls `strdup` and then never `free`s the duplicated string.

Comment: @Praetorian No, its closed source. I'm trying to trace through the entire thing, to see if I am doing something wrong, because similar operations I've done before did not leak anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know how to solve this problem for unique ownership, using `unique_ptr`'s nifty feature where its managed type becomes `Deleter::pointer`, instead of `T*`, if the former type exists.

Assuming you don't have the definition of `Synset`, or whatever type `SynsetPtr` points to, the problem with using a `shared_ptr` is that it doesn't have the same facility of switching the managed type, and if you create a `shared_ptr<SynsetPtr>`, the constructor will expect a `SynsetPtr*`, but your C API functions don't return that type. And I don't know for sure whether using `shared_ptr<remove_pointer<SynsetPtr>::type>` will compile if you don't have the definition of the type that dereferencing a `SynsetPtr` yields.

This *might* work, but I'm not sure.

```
std::shared_ptr<std::remove_pointer<SynsetPtr>::type>
make_findtheinfo_ds(char *searchstr, int pos, int ptr_type, int sense_num)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<std::remove_pointer<SynsetPtr>::type>
               (findtheinfo_ds(searchstr, pos, ptr_type, sense_num),
                free_syns);
}

std::shared_ptr<std::remove_pointer<SynsetPtr>::type>
make_traceptrs_ds(SynsetPtr synptr, int ptr_type, int pos, int depth)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<std::remove_pointer<SynsetPtr>::type>
               (traceptrs_ds(synptr, ptr_type, pos, depth),
                free_synset);
}
```

Going the unique ownership route, I'd make a couple of factory functions that return `unique_ptr`s managing `SynsetPtr`s.

We need 2 separate deleters for the different kinds of `SynsetPtr`s

```
struct sense_list_del
{
    using pointer = SynsetPtr;
    void operator()(SynsetPtr p)
    {
        free_syns(p);
    }
};

struct linked_list_del
{
    using pointer = SynsetPtr;
    void operator()(SynsetPtr p)
    {
        free_synset(p);
    }
};

std::unique_ptr<SynsetPtr, sense_list_del>
make_findtheinfo_ds(char *searchstr, int pos, int ptr_type, int sense_num)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<SynsetPtr, sense_list_del>
               (findtheinfo_ds(searchstr, pos, ptr_type, sense_num));
}

std::unique_ptr<SynsetPtr, linked_list_del>
make_traceptrs_ds(SynsetPtr synptr, int ptr_type, int pos, int depth)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<SynsetPtr, linked_list_del>
               (traceptrs_ds(synptr, ptr_type, pos, depth));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that’s a very interesting approach. I will test everything tomorrow (its almost 6:00am here).

Comment: Hi! I have used the shared_ptr, as it seems more appropriate because I keep re-using the same pointers. However, I have run into a pickle I don't quite understand: auto next = std::make_shared<Synset>(ptr->nextss); Produces errors. No matter how I try to work around it. The allocator complains about the parameter. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Alex You can't use `make_shared`. Your call is attempting to construct a `Synset` by calling `Synset::Synset(ptr->nextss)`, which doesn't exist. You can use the solution I posted for `shared_ptr` above, or the one posted by DavidRodriguez. They should both work.

Comment: So there’s no way to construct directly a shared pointer from a raw Synset pointer because the structure has no constructor?

Comment: @Alex Precisely; your *constructors* in this case are those two functions that return `SynsetPtr`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `std::shared_ptr` for this purpose, as you can provide the *deleter* to use to free the pointer.

```
std::shared_ptr<Synset> findTheInfo(...) {
    std::shared_ptr<Synset> sp(findtheinfo(...), free_syns);
    return sp;
}
std::shared_ptr<Synset> tracePtrs(...) {
    std::shared_ptr<Synset> sp(traceptrs(...), free_synset);
    return sp;
}
```

Now, if they really represent different things, you might want to spend a bit more effort and provide two types that wrap each use and provide the appropriate interface. Does it make sense to treat both as the same type when transversing a list and a tree might be completely different?

Comment: Are you sure this will compile? The `shared_ptr` constructor will expect to receive `SynsetPtr *`s, but those C functions return `SynsetPtr`s

Comment: @Praetorian: The details are not present in the question, so it is hard to know what is really returned by the function. Often times a library that requires that you call `free_XXX` will have provided a pointer in the *allocator* function. I imagine that the `Ptr` in `SynsetPtr` might indicate a typedef of a pointer type (I have also corrected the code there), but again, without the actual signatures it is all guessing work. *Am I sure this will compile?* By no means.

Comment: Yep, there is too little information to go on, but I was assuming the same, that `SynsetPtr` is a typedef for a pointer type, but whatever type deferencing one yields is opaque. What if you were to use `shared_ptr<remove_pointer<SynsetPtr>::type>` (if the type `Synset` doesn't exist?); would that work with an opaque type in this case?

Comment: @Praetorian: `shared_ptr` does not care whether the type is incomplete if you provide a deleter. It will pass the whole thing back to the deleter and hope that it knows how to sort it out.