# WordNet SynSet ptrlist from findtheinfo_ds() only goes one level

Tags: c++, c, wordnet

I'm trying to call the WordNet C API from my C++ application, and it works, but not as expected. Here's my code:

```
int search (char* term)
{
    results.clear();

    SynsetPtr synsets = findtheinfo_ds(term, NOUN, HYPERPTR, ALLSENSES);
    SynsetPtr currentSynset = synsets;

    // Loop all senses
    while (currentSynset != nullptr)
    {
        SynsetPtr next = currentSynset;

        // Iterate up hierarchy for each sense.
        while (next != nullptr)
        {
            String words;

            for (int i = 0; i != next->wcount; ++i)
            {
                String nextWord = next->words[i];
                nextWord = nextWord.replaceCharacter('_', ' ');

                words += String(nextWord);
                if (i != (next->wcount - 1)) words += ", ";
            }

            results.add (words + " - " + String(next->defn));

            next = next->ptrlist;
        }

        currentSynset = currentSynset->nextss;
    }

    free_syns(synsets);

    return results.size();
}
```

My program correctly outputs the definition of each of the senses, but for each sense, it only outputs the ONE hypernym directly above my search term in the hierarchy, it doesn't go all the way up the tree to 'entity'. In other words, the second SynsetPtr->ptrlist is always NULL, even when I can see from the WordNet CLI that there are many levels up.

Am I missing something? Am I calling findtheinfo_ds() incorrectly?

Comment: Is `next != nullptr` safe?  Maybe `next != NULL`?  Minor: Suggest `for (int i = 0; i < next->wcount; ++i)`

Comment: @chux I think it's safe, but I don't have a lot of experience calling into C. I've changed it to `NULL`, but no change in behavior.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/21745260/841830  (Not directly about this topic, but talks about issues of using the C API, and this function in particular, from C++).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findtheinfo_ds()` only returns one node. To work your way through the tree you have to call `findtheinfo_ds()` for each connection it finds. I found [this page](http://wwbota.free.fr/misc/explore_WordNet_Synset_struct.txt) which shows a gdb interactive session on the returned data structure, which I think you will find useful.

Also take a look at the `traceptrs_ds()` function, which sounds like it might be designed for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what should the search string I pass to findtheinfo_ds() from the second node be? I tried ptr->words[ptr->whichword], but it resulted in an infinite loop, looping through several terms repeatedly.

Comment: I think that is why you want to use `traceptrs_ds()`, as it takes a `SynsetPtr` instead of a `char*`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Darren Cook for pointing me in the right direction.

The correct solution is to call `findtheinfo_ds()` to get the start node. Then iterate through each of the senses getting the `synset->nextss` of each for the head node of the next sense.

For each of those sense head nodes, first print the `syn->words` or `syn->defn` for the definition. Then call `traceptrs_ds()` passing the head node and a depth of 1 (which means we're requesting a recursive search to get all the nodes up to "entity"). Then iterate up from the node `traceptrs_ds()` returns to get all the (in my case) hypernyms for that sense. Here's my updated code:

```
int setSearch (char* term)
{
    results.clear();

    SynsetPtr synsets = findtheinfo_ds(term, NOUN, HYPERPTR, ALLSENSES);
    SynsetPtr currentSynset = synsets;

    // Loop all senses
    while (currentSynset != NULL)
    {
        // Function that prints the synset->defn i.e. the definition of this sense.
        printSynsetDef(currentSynset);

        // Call this to get the hypernyms for this sense, with next->ptrlist linked as expected.
        SynsetPtr next = traceptrs_ds(currentSynset, *currentSynset->ptrtyp, *currentSynset->ppos, 1);

        // Iterate up/down tree for each sense.
        while (next != NULL)
        {
            printSynsetDef(next);

            next = next->ptrlist;
        }

        // Don't forget to free the list. Hairy C!
        free_syns(next);

        currentSynset = currentSynset->nextss;
    }

    // And free the original list.
    free_syns(synsets);

    return results.size();
}
```