# stopping std::shared_ptr wrappers of C pointers from SIGSEV due to multiple frees

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, shared-ptr, wordnet

This question relates to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21745260/wrapping-around-old-c-structures-with-smart-pointers-in-c11-and-auto-freeing-t) I asked a year ago.
I am using WordNet 3.0 which was written a long time ago in C (circa 1996 I think).

In order to try and stay away from memory management, I asked how I could wrap `std::shared_ptr` around the old `struct Synset` used by WordNet.

A [reference table](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/man/wnsearch.3WN.html) shows the WordNet-3.0 functions, and inspection of [the actual header](https://code.google.com/p/wordnet2vs2008/source/browse/trunk/include/wn.h) shows that the `SynsetPtr`,
which functions `traceptrs_ds` and `findtheinfo_ds` return, are  pointers to `ss` or `Synset`.

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21745260/wrapping-around-old-c-structures-with-smart-pointers-in-c11-and-auto-freeing-t) I chose to remove the pointer,
and then wrap it around a `shared_ptr` like so:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::remove_pointer<SynsetPtr>::type>
               (findtheinfo_ds(searchstr, pos, ptr_type, sense_num),
                free_syns);

std::shared_ptr<std::remove_pointer<SynsetPtr>::type>
               (traceptrs_ds(synptr, ptr_type, pos, depth),
                free_synset);
```

I have two loops, one which iterates `senses` by following the `nextss`, and one which traverses a tree list by calling `traceptrs_ds`.
Those are the two loops (oversimplified):

```
std::shared_ptr<Synset> synsets;
synsets = std::shared_ptr<std::remove_pointer<SynsetPtr>::type>
          (findtheinfo_ds(const_cast<char*>(key.c_str()), lexical, HYPERPTR, ALLSENSES),free_syns);
if (synsets)
{
    std::shared_ptr<Synset> sense_ptr = synsets;
    while(sense_ptr)
    {
        graph g = graph();
        iterate(sense_ptr, nullptr, g, 0, lexical);
        sense_ptr = std::shared_ptr<std::remove_pointer<SynsetPtr>::type>(sense_ptr->nextss);
    }
}

iterate(
          std::shared_ptr<Synset> ptr,
          std::shared_ptr<layer> last,
          graph & rhs,
          int i,
          int lexical
       )
{
    while (ptr)
    {
        i++;
        ptr  = std::shared_ptr<std::remove_pointer<SynsetPtr>::type>
               (traceptrs_ds(ptr.get(), HYPERPTR, lexical, 1), free_synset);
    }
}
```

From what I understand (feel free to correct me) many `std::shared_ptr` are wrapping around the same memory,
and when their destructor is called, they try to free the same memory.

#### How can I prevent this from happening?

I know that `findtheinfo_ds` returns a linked list, and that each call to `traceptrs_ds` appears to iterate that list.
I image that the best approach would be to wrap only one `std::shared_ptr` which is going to call the `Synset` destructor `free_synset`, instead of doing it many times.

#### How can I stop this from happening?

Assuming there is no solution to prevent this from happening,
how can the destructors of the many `std::shared_ptr` that map to the same area, only free once?
I guess this is a bad/ugly way, but it may be easier?

The `valgrind` output:

```
==3066== Invalid read of size 8
==3066==    at 0x52C3B4C: free_synset (in /usr/lib/libwordnet-3.0.so)
==3066==    by 0x4E6E2D9: std::_Sp_counted_deleter<ss*, void (*)(ss*), std::allocator<void>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_dispose() (shared_ptr_base.h:463)
==3066==    by 0x403C5F: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() (shared_ptr_base.h:149)
==3066==    by 0x403AD8: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() (shared_ptr_base.h:666)
==3066==    by 0x4E61DB7: std::__shared_ptr<ss, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() (shared_ptr_base.h:914)
==3066==    by 0x4E61DD1: std::shared_ptr<ss>::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.h:93)
==3066==    by 0x4E6161A: smnet::hyper_handler::operator()(std::string, int) (hyper_handler.cpp:22)
==3066==    by 0x4036D6: main (hypernym.cpp:16)
==3066==  Address 0x10 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

==3066== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==3066==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x10
==3066==    at 0x52C3B4C: free_synset (in /usr/lib/libwordnet-3.0.so)
==3066==    by 0x4E6E2D9: std::_Sp_counted_deleter<ss*, void (*)(ss*), std::allocator<void>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_dispose() (shared_ptr_base.h:463)
==3066==    by 0x403C5F: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() (shared_ptr_base.h:149)
==3066==    by 0x403AD8: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() (shared_ptr_base.h:666)
==3066==    by 0x4E61DB7: std::__shared_ptr<ss, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() (shared_ptr_base.h:914)
==3066==    by 0x4E61DD1: std::shared_ptr<ss>::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.h:93)
==3066==    by 0x4E6161A: smnet::hyper_handler::operator()(std::string, int) (hyper_handler.cpp:22)
==3066==    by 0x4036D6: main (hypernym.cpp:16)

==3066== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3066==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3066==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3066==      possibly lost: 251 bytes in 8 blocks
==3066==    still reachable: 19,964 bytes in 90 blocks
==3066==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3066== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==3066== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==3066== 
==3066== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3066== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
fish: “valgrind --leak-check=full ./hy…” terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, after searching quite a bit, I found the solution using struct functors and lambdas. Granted its not pretty (in fact its quite ugly) but seems to work:

```
struct sense_del
{
    void operator()(Synset *ptr)
    {
        if (ptr)
            free_syns(ptr);
    }
};

struct trace_del
{
    void operator()(Synset *ptr)
    {
        if (ptr)
            free_synset(ptr);
    }
};

std::shared_ptr<Synset>
shared_findtheinfo_ds(std::string key, int gram_type, int ptr_type, int sense_num)
{
    wn_init_once();
    std::shared_ptr<Synset> sp(findtheinfo_ds(const_cast<char*>(key.c_str()), gram_type, ptr_type, sense_num),
                               [](Synset * ptr){sense_del()(ptr);});
    return sp;
}

std::shared_ptr<Synset> 
shared_traceptrs_ds(SynsetPtr synptr, int ptr_type, int gram_type, int depth)
{
    assert(synptr);
    std::shared_ptr<Synset> sp(traceptrs_ds(synptr, ptr_type, gram_type, depth),
                              [](Synset *ptr){trace_del()(ptr);});
    return sp;
}
```

FYI, for anyone working on Wordnet, the correct way of iteration for Hypernyms is this:

```
if (auto ss_ptr = findtheinfo_ds(const_cast<char*>(key.c_str()), lexical, HYPERPTR, ALLSENSES))
{
    while(ss_ptr)
    {
        if (SynsetPtr trc_ptr = traceptrs_ds(ss_ptr, HYPERPTR, lexical, 1))
        {
            do_smth_with_it(trc_ptr);
            free_syns(trc_ptr);
        }
        // get next sense 
        ss_ptr = ss_ptr->nextss;
    }
    free_syns(ss_ptr);
}
```